# 2000 Dodge Ram 8 cyl Doesn't want to run, Have to keep foot on the gas

Tags: starting, dodge, radiator, ram

Today, went to leave and my truck would not start. It is not the Battery. When checking all my fluids noticed I needed water. Pour water in radiator and it all came out under the motor area.

Comment: Can you update your 'question' to make it clear what you want to know?

Comment: That and please be very specific. Also, when you say "water" do you literally mean water, or an ethalyne glycol mix? And did you really pour it into the radiator, or into the coolant reservoir?